# How to design a database schema for a messaging app?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm creating a laravel website which has Messaging as an included feature.
I would like to take into consideration the following factors.

1. Both parties (the sender and the receiver) have the ability to delete the messages in their end.
2. if any of the parties deleted the message the other party should still having access to the message.
3. the message might have attachments.

I thought of the following schema but I think it has too much duplication and I'm looking for something better if any.

```
messages table:
-----------------
id
title
body
```

```
received_messages table:
------------------------
message_id
receiver_id
sender_id
is_read
```

```
sent_messages table:
------------------------
message_id
receiver_id
sender_id
```

**Edit: Another schema came to my mind:**

```
messages table:
-----------------
id
title
body
```

```
user_messages table:
-----------------
message_id
sender_id
receiver_id
sender_del   // indicates that the sender deleted the message in their end
receiver_del // indicates that the receiver deleted the message in their end
read_at      // timestamp null by default
```

When one party choose delete the message the corresponding field (sender_del, receiver_del) will be true so that the message will not be shown to that person

Using the previous schema the message will only be deleted from the DB if both parties deleted it

```php
<?php
$user = auth()->user();
$received = $user->receivedMessages; // to get received messages
$sent = $user->sentMessages; // to get sent messages
```

any suggested modifications, which schema to use or a whole new schema are welcomed.
Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you merge all of this in one table?

Comment: And a message can only ever be between 2 people?

Comment: the main problem I'm trying to solve here is how to keep the message in case one of the parties (sender, receiver) decided to delete it in their end. but one table with flags still an option @MuhammadUmair

Comment: It's not a chatting application, it's kinda of direct messages, think of it as SMS messages. @Strawberry

Comment: Why do you want to keep your msg in separate table? So there can be multiple recipients of msg?

Comment: I'm still figuring out which schema to go with none of them is final, hopefully someone come with a better idea @MuhammadUmair